# Smooth scroll on listview with calllogs

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom adapter added to listview. Data is call logs from phone. I reduce list by show only records from 3 days. Problem is that when I try to scroll listview from top to bottom I have a huge lags. My Scroll isn't smooth. Is there any way to make listview scroll smoother?

Here is my custom adapter:

```
    public class CallListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CallList> {

    Activity activity;

    public CallListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CallList> calls, Activity activity) {
        super(context, 0, calls);
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final CallList callList = getItem(position);

        int actualPosition = 0;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.call_list, parent, false);
        }

        final TextView call1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.callNumber);
        final TextView call2 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.callDate);
        final TextView call3 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.conversationTime);
        final TextView call4 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.callType);
        final Button callView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.getViewName);
        final ImageView bio = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lookBio);
        final ImageView edit = convertView.findViewById(R.id.edit_call);
        final ImageView block = convertView.findViewById(R.id.blockCall);
        final ImageView call = convertView.findViewById(R.id.callUser);
        final TextView bioLabel = convertView.findViewById(R.id.BioLabelSug);
        final TextView editLabel = convertView.findViewById(R.id.NoteLabel);
        final TextView blockLabel = convertView.findViewById(R.id.BlockLabelSug);
        final TextView callLabel = convertView.findViewById(R.id.CallLabelSug);
        final ConstraintLayout callContainer = convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_container);
        final ConstraintLayout bioContainer = convertView.findViewById(R.id.bio_container);
        final ConstraintLayout blockContainer = convertView.findViewById(R.id.ignore_container);
        final ConstraintLayout noteContainer = convertView.findViewById(R.id.note_container);
        final TextView btnMarg = convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonMargin);
        final TextView callListNr2 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.callNumber2);

        final LayoutInflater factory = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        final View fullView = factory.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calls, null);

        final RelativeLayout loading = fullView.findViewById(R.id.loadingBar);


        String[] jsonData = new manageCalls().intentCallValues(position);

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : jsonData) {
            builder.append(s + "\n");
        }
        String str = builder.toString();

        final String num = jsonData[0];
        final String dat = jsonData[1];
        final String typeCall = jsonData[2];
        final String dur = jsonData[3];
        final String authToken = SaveSharedPreferences.getPrefTokenName(getContext());

        final Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slideup);
        final Animation slideDown = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slidedown);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        callView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (bioContainer.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {

                    callListNr2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    bio.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bioLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else if (bioContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            bio.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            callContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            bioContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            noteContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            blockContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }, 300);

                }
            }
        });


        if (actualPosition != position) {

            if (bioContainer.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {

                bioContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                callContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                noteContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                blockContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            actualPosition = position;

        }


        call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                call.setEnabled(false);
                loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Intent intentCall = new Intent(view.getContext(), CallUserActivity.class);

                intentCall.putExtra("number", num);
                intentCall.putExtra("authToken", authToken);
                intentCall.putExtra("Date", dat);

                activity.startActivityForResult(intentCall, position);

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        call.setEnabled(true);
                        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });

        call2.setText(callList.callDate);
        call3.setText(callList.conversationTime);
        call4.setText(callList.callType);

        return convertView;
        }
}
```

Comment: You should use ViewHolder to hold all views in layout.

Comment: Use RecyclerView or use ViewHolder to hold the views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use ViewHolder and use AsyncTask to load bitmap.
You can try this way.

```js
    private static class ViewHolder {
            public TextView call1;
            public TextView call2;
            public TextView call3;
            public TextView call4;
            public Button callView;
            public ImageView bio;
            public ImageView edit;
            public ImageView block;
            public ImageView call;
            public TextView bioLabel;
            public TextView editLabel;
            public TextView blockLabel;
            public TextView callLabel;
            public ConstraintLayout callContainer;
            public ConstraintLayout bioContainer;
            public ConstraintLayout blockContainer;
            public ConstraintLayout noteContainer;
            public TextView btnMarg;
            public TextView callListNr2;
    }
    
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
                // inflate the layout
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.call1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id....);
                holder.call2 = convertView.findViewById(R.id....);
                //Same for all other views
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

        holder.call1.setText(....);
        //Lazy load for bitmap
        loadBitmap(yourFileName..., bio)
       
        return convertView;
    }

    static class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

        BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
            // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
            imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
        }

        // Decode image in background.
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(params[0], 300, 300);
        }

        // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
                final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
                if (imageView != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void loadBitmap(String fileName, ImageView imageView) {
        BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        task.execute(fileName);
    }

  public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String fileName,
                                                     int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, options);
    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName, options);
}
```

Comment: Thank you I created ViewHolder before but got an error I forgot a line with .setTag(holder).

Answer (score 1):

Your getview is HUGE.
Your  (if convertview==null) has basically almost no effect as you're setting up the view again anyways.

What you need to do is refactor the getview to not be so slow. one thing you can do is create a class that has all the findviews done already for you and put that then in the .tag of the converted view. change your onclicks to use that as well, in a manner where you don't have to recreate them(other ways to do that exist as well).

ideally your code for if you have a converted view already should be just the .settexts().

depending on the size of your list, you could just get away with creating a view for each callist and avoid recycling the converted views alltogether, in such case you could just create them in advance.

also depending on the size of your list you could just get away with creating a just a simple linearlayout instead inside a scrollview. if your list isn't huge and it's not for some old phones, it works just fine as well (Don't knock on this as bad advice until you try on your phone how huge it can be before a listview starts making more sense).